# Options Call stalling randomly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, browser, cross-browser, jetty

**Some of our calls are stalling randomly.**

[image]

**Browser Logs:**
(which shows that server is sending empty response)

```
t=231109 [st=    1]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=231109 [st=    1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=27272]
t=231109 [st=    1]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=27272]
                           --> net_error = -324 (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
t=258381 [st=27273]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_RESTART_AFTER_ERROR
                           --> net_error = -324 (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
t=258381 [st=27273]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t=258381 [st=27273]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=1]
t=258381 [st=27273]        HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                           --> source_dependency = 1121189 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=258381 [st=27273]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                           --> source_dependency = 1121190 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=258382 [st=27274]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=258382 [st=27274]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=258382 [st=27274]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
```

**Backend configurations:**

- AWS Network Load balancer
- Jetty server: jetty-9.4.11.v20180605

We can see in the jetty logs that request is coming till Jetty.
Jetty does not process the request and the request gets timeout after 30 seconds (Since, idle-timeout is set to 30 seconds).

We don't have any server load as well. Also, there are no threads stuck in the jstack as well.

I have tried almost everything now, still no clue. Any direction will be really appreciated.

Comment: What on Jetty is processing the OPTIONS request?  Jetty itself is rarely involved in this, usually it's some kind of 3rd party library (rest/jaxrs, spring-mvc, etc...)

Comment: We are using `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter` this filter for serving options call.